# Pass Checkbox text data into another checkbox on a seperate activity page in Xamarin C# Android?

Tags: c#, android, listview, checkbox, xamarin

I have set up where my checkboxes when checked get sent to anther checkbox on a separate activity. I need to figure out how to move each selected checkbox to its own checkbox. Here is the code I have right now that sends all of the selected checkboxes to the other activity page as one checkbox.

```
[Activity (Label = "Songression")]          
public class numbersActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    { 
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        //Variables
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.numbers);
        CheckBox cb0 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox0);
        CheckBox cb1 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        CheckBox cb2 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox2);
        CheckBox cb3 = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.checkBox3);
        Button button0 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button0);
        //Back Button
        button0.Click += delegate {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            };
        //Get Results button
        Button button01 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button01);
            button01.Click += delegate {
            if (cb0.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb0.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;

                    };
            if (cb1.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb1.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;

                    };
            if (cb2.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb2.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    };
            if (cb3.Checked) {
                myResources.result100 += cb3.Text + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    };
            StartActivity (typeof(results));
        };
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code for the results page that the checkboxes are suppoed to be sent to

```
[Activity (Label = "Songression")]          
public class results : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.results);
        //Variables



        CheckBox post = FindViewById<CheckBox> (Resource.Id.result100);
        post.Text = myResources.result100;

        //Back Button
        Button button0 = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.button0);
            button0.Click += delegate {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
                };
        //Save Button
        Button buttonS = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.buttonS);
            buttonS.Click += delegate {
        };
    }
}
```

}

Here is the xml for the results page

`

```
        <CheckBox
            android:text="CheckBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/result100" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the information into the intent extras. Below is a quick example how to pass them.

```
        button.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Results));
                intent.PutExtra("cbs", new[] { cb1.Checked, cb2.Checked, cb3.Checked, cb4.Checked });
                intent.PutExtra("texts", new[] { cb1.Text, cb2.Text, cb3.Text, cb4.Text });
                this.StartActivity(intent);
            };
    }
}

[Activity(Label = "Results", MainLauncher = false, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Results : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var cbs = this.Intent.Extras.GetBooleanArray("cbs");
        var texts = this.Intent.Extras.GetStringArray("texts");

        foreach (var cb in cbs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cb);
        }

        foreach (var text in texts)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(text);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an invalid token for the foreach method. How would I fix this? thank you so much for your help. I believe you may have solved this problem for me.